# Matlab average number of customers during a single day

Tags: matlab

I'm having problems creating a graph of the average number of people inside a 24h shopping complex. I have two columns of data on a spreadsheet of the times a customer comes in (intime) and when he leaves (outtime). The data spans a couple of years and is in datetime format (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss).

I want to make a graph of the data with time of day as x-axis, and average number of people as y-axis. So the graph would display the average number of people inside during the day.

Problems arise because the place is open 24h and the timespan of data is years. Also customer intime & outtime might be on different days.

Example:

intime 2.1.2017 21:50

outtime 3.1.2017 8:31

Any idea how to display the data easily using Matlab?
Been on this for multiple hours without any progress...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to decide what defines a customer being in the shop during the day, is 1 min enough? is there a minimum time length under which you don't want to count it as a visit?

In the former case you shouldn't be concerned with the hours at all, and just count it as 1 entry if the entry and exit are in the same day or as 2 different entries if not.

It's been a couple of years since I coded actively in matlab and I don't have a handy IDE but if you add the code you got so far, I can fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start by just plotting the raw count of people in the complex at the given times.  Once that is visualized it may help you determine how you want to define "average people per day" and how to go about calculating it.  Does that mean average at a given time or total "ins" per day?  Ex. 100 people enter the complex in a day ... but on average there are only 5 in the complex at a given time.  Which stat is more important?  Maybe you want both.

Here is an example of how to get the raw plot of # of people at any given time.  I simulated your in & out time with random numbers.

```
inTime  = cumsum(rand(100,1));  %They show up randomly
outTime = inTime + rand(100,1) + 0.25;  % Stay for 0.25 to 1.25 hrs

inCount  = ones(size(inTime));  %Add one for each entry
outCount = ones(size(outTime))*-1; %Subtract one for each exit.

allTime  = [inTime; outTime]; %Stick them together.
allCount = [inCount; outCount];

[allTime, idx] = sort(allTime);%Sort the timestamps
allCount = allCount(idx); %Sort counts by the timestamps
allCount = cumsum(allCount); %total at any given time.

plot(allTime,allCount);%total at any given time.
```

Note that the x-values are not uniformly spaced.

IF you decide are more interested in total customers per day then you could just find the `intTimes` with in a given time range (each day) & probably just ignore the outTimes all together.

Comment: That helped a bit! If I modify the allTime  = [timeofday(inTime); timeofday(outTime)] I get a graph that looks correct (I knowhow the graph should look, that I want out of a test dataset) but the y-axis is messed up! The graph goes below zero, and I know this isn't possible... The graph done this way starts at 0 on 00:00:00, how to correct it so it would start at the average and not 0?